# Animation in stand alone SVG (with ecmascript (and jQuery?!))

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I created an SVG using inkscape and now I want to add some animation according to some logic to it.

I know JavaScript quite well and have basic experience with jQuery. So I thought I can animate my SVG with jQuery as well.

Google finds countless tutorials on how to work with inline SVG embedded in XHTML, but I have a stand-alone SVG and Firefox complains

> Error: b.style is undefined
>
> Source File: [...]jquery.js
>
> Line: 16

Is there a way to get jQuery working? Or, as an alternative, can you recommand another JavaScript library I could use that fulfills the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to try the [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) library. The API was inspired by jQuery so it should be familiar to you.

Also keep in mind that IE doesn't support SVG so having an SVG-only solution won't be portable across major browsers. Raphaël takes care of it for you - it uses VML on IE and SVG on other browsers. It works on Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

You can create SVG using Inkscape and then import the paths to your Raphaël code. See [the talk by Dmitry Baranovskiy](http://blip.tv/file/3731552/) at JSConf 2010.

Comment: Hi, I'd be glad to use Raphaël. I don't need the script to work cross-platform. If it works on the most recent version of opera or firefox, then I'm fine. Do you know a stand alone example? Because I found inline SVG examples, only, so far.

Comment: There's a raphael-svg-import at https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import/#readme but I haven't used it myself so I can't say how good is it. Depending on your image you may try to manually extract paths from your SVG image as shown by Dmitry in the talk I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the last answer. Drop your SVG into the converter at

http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/svgsource.php

This will put your SVG into html4 and it will work on all browsers except android.
You can animate the paths with Raphael.

The output from the converter is all Raphael / SVG / VML

Comment: It does sound like a reasonable solution, but I still need the SVG as a string which I don't like. If I copy the SVG around from one file to another, then I can also use inline SVG and jQuery. Maybe it would be cool to combine this with some Ajax to load a seperate SVG file with javascript and parse it. But it still does not feel very natural to me.