# jquery animating svg graphics without using the svg plugin or ui library only the core

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

can anyone give me some advice on how to animate svg graphics using jquery core only? basically what i want to be able to do is enlarge the graphic by 10% on hover and also add some css3 styles?

All advice would be great

Kyle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/LpPdP/**

**Notes:**

- **The SVG image is simply an image.**  You can do anything to an SVG image that you can with a normal image.
- **You can style via `.hover` class.**  I chose to add the class `hover` when you hover, as that made the most sense.

Comment: thanks for the response, my problem lays however with trying to animate individual paths, i have tried adding a class to a path and then tried to animate that class but get no response?

Comment: I'd HIGHLY recommend using a jQuery plug-in for that, mate.  The plugins I have seen are extremely large, and probably for good reason.